# Youtube API Subscription.ContentDetails.TotalItemCount and NewItemCount are broken

Tags: youtube-api

I've been using the v3 Youtube API through C# recently, and have noticed that with the Subscriptions.List API, the TotalItemCount and NewItemCount in the ContentDetails property of the returned subscription seem to be incorrect.

TotalItemCount is always 0, and NewItemCount is unpredictable. I usually see it as 0, but sometimes it's 2 or 3 or whatnot. It's described in the [API spec](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#resource) as "The number of new items in the subscription since its content was last read." However even if I query it multiple times the number stays the same, and doesn't seem tied to anything I can figure out.

You can try out the API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it), you need to enable Oauth with the Youtube scope, pass part=contentDetails and set Mine to true.